# Retained messages in the MQTT Message Protocol

Tags: mqtt, hivemq, mqttnet, mqtt.js

I'm working with two **MQTT client libs**: One for ***Angular*** 14 (in my browser application), and the other is Mqtt ***4.1.4 .Net*** client for Framework 4.6.

At one point I was publishing an MQTT test message from my front-end application with `retain: true`. However, in my .Net logs I kept getting those messages over and over again - HUNDREDS OF THEM.

And now that I turned OFF the retain flag in my front end app, of course now those older retained messages keep flooding my logs.

Two questions :

1. Why am I getting so many duplicates when Subscribing to topic `myapp/from-har-app`.
2. How can I delete the RETAINED message? I read on HiveMq docs that I can just publish an empty payload on that same topic..

   ```
   string message = "";
   this.Publish(message, "harmony/from-my-app"); // TRY TO DELETE RETAINED MSG !
   ```

Here's the `OnSubscribe` method in .Net 4.6 :

```js
private Task OnSubscriberMessageReceived(MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs x)
  {
      var item = $"{ x.ApplicationMessage.ConvertPayloadToString()}";
      applog.Info($"Mqtt OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: {item} {x.ApplicationMessage.Topic}");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
```

```js
using log4net.Ext.EventID;
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient;
using MQTTnet.Formatter;
using MQTTnet.Packets;
using MQTTnet.Protocol;
using MQTTnet.Server;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
using MqttNotificationService.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MqttNotificationService
  {
    public partial class MqttService : ServiceBase
    {
        public static readonly IEventIDLog applog = EventIDLogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        private IManagedMqttClient managedMqttClientPublisher;
        private IManagedMqttClient managedMqttClientSubscriber;
        private string mqttClientUser = "";
        private byte[] mqttClientPswd;

        private string mqttBrokerAddress;
        private string mqttProtocol = "wss";
        private int? mqttPort;
        private string defaultMessage;

        private string topicThisHost = "";      // get topic from app.config
        private string heartBeatPubMsg;
        private double heartBeatTimerMs;
        
    public MqttService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Init();
        CreateThreadAndRun();
        StartHeartBeatTimer();
    }

      private void Init()
      {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        mqttClientUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttClientUser"];
        // pulling additional keys here...
      }

      private void StartPublisherAndSubscriber()
      {
          StartSubscriber();
          _ = StartPublisher();
          CheckOtherServers();
      }

      private void StartHeartBeatTimer()
      {
          TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
          Thread.Sleep(ts);

          Timer timer = new Timer();
          timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(PublishHeartBeat);
          timer.Interval = heartBeatTimerMs;
          timer.Enabled = true;
      }

      private void PublishHeartBeat(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
          var message = $"{ this.heartBeatPubMsg}: { MyHostName} {hostIp}";
          _ = this.Publish(message, topicThisHost);
          this.CheckOtherServers();
      }

       public async Task Publish(string messageIn, string topic, IManagedMqttClient pubClient = null)
      {
          MqttQualityOfServiceLevel qos = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce;
          switch (MqttQos)
          {
              case 0:
                  qos = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce;
                  break;
              case 1:
                  qos = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtMostOnce;
                  break;
              case 2:
                  qos = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.ExactlyOnce;
                  break;
          }
          MqttModel message = new MqttModel();
          message.message = messageIn;
          message.datestamp = DateTime.Now;
          message.source = "";
          message.status = "";
          var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, Formatting.Indented);

          var send = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
              .WithTopic(topic)
              .WithPayload(payload)
              .WithQualityOfServiceLevel(qos)
              .WithRetainFlag(false)
              .Build();

          if (this.managedMqttClientPublisher == null)
          {
              this.managedMqttClientPublisher = pubClient;
          }

          if (this.managedMqttClientPublisher != null)
          {
              try
              {
                  applog.Debug($"Mqtt Service Publish() method - about to pub mqtt message EnqueueAsync() - {messageIn} / {topic} ");
                  await this.managedMqttClientPublisher.EnqueueAsync(send);
                  MonitoringLogs logs = new MonitoringLogs();
                  logs.InsertIntoLog(message);
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  string errorMessage = $"Exception occured in Publish() method. {ex.Message}";
                  applog.Error(errorMessage);
                  throw new Exception(errorMessage);
              }
          }
          else
          {
              applog.Info($"Mqtt Service Publish() method - managedMqttClientPublisher object appears to be NULL");
          }
      }
  
  public ManagedMqttClientOptions WsSecureClientOptions()
        {
            string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MqttService)).CodeBase);

            // Building out the secure wss url (both pfx/crt certificate file types appear to work here)
            var url = $"{mqttBrokerAddress}:{mqttPort}/mqtt";

            X509Certificate2 x509Cert = null;
            var file = CertificateFileName;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, file).Remove(0, 6);

            // pfx file contains both pub and priv keys (needs pswd); crt file only has pub key (no pswd req'd)
            if (Path.GetExtension(CertificateFileName.ToLower()) == ".pfx")
            {
                // using a PFX cert file via the X509 class
                x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(filePath, CertificatePwd);
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(CertificateFileName.ToLower()) == ".crt")
            {
                x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(filePath);
            }

            applog.Debug($"In WsSecureClientOptions(), Certificate Path - {filePath}");          

            var clientOptionsBldr = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                        .WithProtocolVersion(MqttProtocolVersion.V500)
                                        .WithWebSocketServer(url)
                                        .WithCredentials(mqttClientUser, mqttClientPswd)
                                        .WithClientId(clientId)
                                        .WithCleanSession()
                                        .WithCredentials(mqttClientUser, mqttClientPswd)
                                        .WithTls(
                                            new MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters()
                                            {
                                                UseTls = true,
                                                SslProtocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
                                                Certificates = new List<X509Certificate2>() { x509Cert }                                              
                                            });
            ManagedMqttClientOptions managedClientOptions = null;
            try
            {
                applog.Debug($"In WsSecureClientOptions(), about to Build Publisher - ${url}");
                managedClientOptions = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                                                .WithClientOptions(clientOptionsBldr)
                                                                .Build();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                applog.Error("CERT ERROR ! Exception in WsSecureClientOptions() " + ex.Message);
            }

            return managedClientOptions;
        }

    private Task OnSubscriberConnected(MqttClientConnectedEventArgs _)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task OnSubscriberDisconnected(MqttClientDisconnectedEventArgs _)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
 }
```

Here's my log just now, after debugging my .Net project locally - the older retained message from 11:19:37 is still hitting my logs. The `newest test msg` I sent is the 3rd from bottom at `11:49`:

```html
2023-03-24 11:48:24   INFO  OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:48:57   INFO OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:48:32   INFO OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:49:04 INFO OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:49:06  INFO OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:49:09   INFO OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:49:16   INFO OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:49:17  INFO OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:49:18 ( DEBUG Mqtt Publish() method - I am alive, from  MqttWinSvc: : ... @2023-03-24 11:49:18 AM /client/internal/admin/host/MyHostName 


2023-03-24 11:49:19  INFO  Mqtt Service OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:49:26   INFO  Mqtt Service OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:49:27  INFO  Mqtt Service OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app

*** (NEW MSG) 2023-03-24 11:49:33 (null) [20]  INFO  Mqtt Service OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:49:32 AM myapp/from-har-app ***

2023-03-24 11:49:40 (null) [28]  INFO  Mqtt Service OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
2023-03-24 11:49:46 (null) [30]  INFO  Mqtt Service OnSubscriberMessageReceived() method - message/topic: Hello from browser - 11:19:37 AM myapp/from-har-app
```

It just seems that I'm getting too many duplicates message in both front-end and .Net clients. I'm also tweaking the QoS value btwn 0/1/2 to see what happens.

Thanks for the advice...

Comment: Regarding why you receive so many copies - it's likely that your client is in a connect/disconnect loop (every time it connects it will get the retained messages). A common cause if this is connecting multiple times with the same client id (broker will drop existing connection).

Comment: My Mqtt .Net client is running in a .Net Windows Service (Framework 4.6), and there is a "heartbeat" msg sent to the broker (via a c# Timer). Perhaps this is where it is doing the connect/disconnect...

Comment: @Brits - Indeed you are right. As I debug my VS2019 project (i.e. attach to process, while the WinSvc is running), I'm constantly breaking in `OnSubscriberConnected` and `OnSubscriberDisconnected` over and over again. Then sure enough, the next event method I hit is `OnSubscriberMessageReceived` - and I'm receiving the SAME retained msg each time.

Comment: So you need to work out why the connection is dropping. Your question does not provide enough detail for me to make any suggestions on that point.

Comment: @Brits - I have updated my post to include the various methods getting called in my service code.

Comment: Sorry - I'd need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); there are too many unknowns (missing values/code) and irrelevant detail in the above. I would suggest that you fix the reconnect loop before looking at other issues (if you are at QOS1/2 then the disconnect could cause repeats if the relevant acknowledgments have not made it to the broker). The broker logs would also be worth a look (you should be able to confirm that the duplicate messages are from the broker and why it's sending them).

Comment: @Brits I will create a new post specifically for the conn/disconn issues.

Comment: @Brits - I dug in further and found the args values passed into `OnSubscriberDisconnected` `args.Reason = SessionTakenOver`

`args.ReasonString = "Another client connected with the same client id."`

Comment: @Brits - please see my new, clean post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903499/mqtt-4-1-4-net-client-connect-disconnect-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear a retained message from a topic you must do the following:

- Publish a message with a `null` (empty) payload
- It needs to be on the same topic
- It must also have the retained flag set

You can do this explicitly with the latest version of the `mosquitto_sub` tool, e.g.

```
mosquitto_sub -t '#' --remove-retained --retained-only
```

This will connect to a broker on localhost and remove ALL the retained messages.

Comment: I tried doing that interactively while debugging my .net project. Perhaps because I sent an empty string "" rather than a null value...I think the tool will benefit me as well, thx.

Comment: I'm also wondering why I'm getting so many duplicates of that Retained msg. I realize that QOS=0 may result in dupes, but the same msg is flooding my logs.

Comment: I downloaded the tool, but just keep getting `connection attempt failed`.

Comment: Have you read the man page for how to pass other options? e.g. hostname, port, username? My example does specifically assume the broker is running on localhost (and on port 1883 with no authentication, because the important bits are `--remove-retained --retained-only`)

Comment: I'm on this page here: https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html (with various options passed) , and checking out Steve's internet guide http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto_pub-sub-clients/

Comment: e.g. `mosquitto_pub -h <my-hivemq-cluster-Url> -u <my-user> -P <my-pass> i- BobTestClient123 -t "test/topic123" -m "pub a test msg from my local box"`  -->  ERROR: `A connection attempt failed...connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Comment: `failed to respond` implies ether the host (**not URL**, just a hostname) or the port is wrong or a firewall between you and the broker.

Comment: funny thing is I'm connecting to the same Broker host/url/port via my browser client on my machine (Angular app running on localhost:4200). So perhaps firewall is blocking, as you mentioned.

Comment: ahh, `mosquitto_sub` doesn't support MQTT over WebSockets

Comment: shouldn't your original answer be `mosquitto_pub` and not `sub` ? Because if I pub a null msg payload, it should remove the retained msg on that topic right?

Comment: @bob.mazzo no, You can do it manually with the `mosquitto_pub` command, but the shortcut is part of `mosquitto_sub`, check the man page https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html