# .net client keeps Connecting and Disconnecting over and over again

Tags: mqtt, hivemq, mqtt.js

I'm running a Windows Service project in VS2019, with `Mqtt 4.1.4 .Net` framework client.

My .net client keeps `Connecting and Disconnecting` over and over again.

I recently discovered that my `OnSubscriberDisconnected` method is passing the following `args` values:

`args.Reason = SessionTakenOver`

`args.ReasonString = "Another client connected with the same client id."`

Initially I had been creating a new random ClientID upon each HiveMq Broker connection (the free cloud version), But I changed it to :

```
 clientId = ".netWinSvc-" + this.machineName;
```

this way the machine which is running my Win Service code will ALWAYS conn with the same ClientID.

I believe I was piling up lots of new ClientID connections, and asking the broker to persist the session (`CleanSession = false`). And the free cloud subscription allows for `100 device connections`.

**QUESTION IS:** What do I do to clean up all of these clientID connections, and how avoid this Disconnect/Reconnect issue? Is re-using the same ClientID with `CleanSession = false` the best way to go ? In other words, shouldn't I ask the broker to `persist` my ClientID connection?

Here is a good portion of my .Net Window Service code:

```js
using log4net.Ext.EventID;
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient;
using MQTTnet.Formatter;
using MQTTnet.Packets;
using MQTTnet.Protocol;
using MQTTnet.Server;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
using MqttNotificationService.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MqttNotificationService
  {
    public partial class MqttService : ServiceBase
    {
        public static readonly IEventIDLog applog = EventIDLogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        private IManagedMqttClient managedMqttClientPublisher;
        private IManagedMqttClient managedMqttClientSubscriber;
        private string mqttClientUser = "";
        private byte[] mqttClientPswd;

        private string mqttBrokerAddress;
        private string mqttProtocol = "wss";
        private int? mqttPort;
        private string defaultMessage;

        private string topicThisHost = "";      // get topic from app.config
        private string heartBeatPubMsg;
        private double heartBeatTimerMs;
        
    public MqttService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Init();
        CreateThreadAndRun();
        StartHeartBeatTimer();
    }

      private void Init()
      {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        mqttClientUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttClientUser"];
        mqttBrokerAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttBrokerAddress"];
        mqttProtocol = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttProtocol"];
        mqttPort = Int16.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttPort"]);
        MqttUseTls = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseTlsCertificate"]);
        var MqttQos = Int16.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QualityOfService"]);
        mqttRetained = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttRetained"]);
        mqttLastWillRetained = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttLastWillRetained"]);
        mqttLastWillMessage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttLastWillMessage"];
        mqttKeepAliveSeconds = Int16.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttLastWillKeepAliveSeconds"]);
        CertificateFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateFileName"];
        CertificatePwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePswd"];

        defaultMessage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPubMessage"];
        topicSubFromHar = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttTopicSubFromHar"];
        topicThisHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MqttTopicThisHost"];
        heartBeatPubMsg = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HeartBeatPubMessage"];
        heartBeatTimerMs = Double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HeartBeatTimerMs"]);
        pingDicom = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CheckDicomServers"]);
        SynergyHostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SynergyHostName"];

        machineName = Dns.GetHostName();
        hostIp = Dns.GetHostEntry(machineName)
            .AddressList
            .FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            .ToString();
       
        clientId = ".netWinSvc-" + this.machineName;

        QosThisHost = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce;
        switch (MqttQos)
        {
            case 0:
                QosThisHost = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce;
                break;
            case 1:
                QosThisHost = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtMostOnce;
                break;
            case 2:
                QosThisHost = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.ExactlyOnce;
                break;
        }
      }

      public void CreateThreadAndRun()
      {
          Thread m_Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartPublisherAndSubscriber));
          m_Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
          m_Thread.Name = "MT";
          m_Thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
          m_Thread.Start();
      }

      private void StartPublisherAndSubscriber()
      {
          StartSubscriber();
          _ = StartPublisher();
          CheckOtherServers();
      }

      private void StartHeartBeatTimer()
      {
          TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
          Thread.Sleep(ts);

          Timer timer = new Timer();
          timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(PublishHeartBeat);
          timer.Interval = heartBeatTimerMs;
          timer.Enabled = true;
      }

      private void PublishHeartBeat(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
          var message = $"{ this.heartBeatPubMsg}: { MyHostName} {hostIp}";
          _ = this.Publish(message, topicThisHost);
          this.CheckOtherServers();
      }

      private async void StartSubscriber()
        {
          applog.Debug($"In StartSubscriber()");

          var mqttFactory = new MQTTnet.MqttFactory();

          managedMqttClientSubscriber = mqttFactory.CreateManagedMqttClient();
          managedMqttClientSubscriber.ConnectedAsync += OnSubscriberConnected;
          managedMqttClientSubscriber.DisconnectedAsync += OnSubscriberDisconnected;
          managedMqttClientSubscriber.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += this.OnSubscriberMessageReceived;

          // If tls is enabled in app.config, we use wss with cert file
          if (MqttUseTls)
          {
              var managedClientOptions = WsSecureClientOptions();
              await managedMqttClientSubscriber.StartAsync(managedClientOptions);
          }
          else
          {
              var insecureOptions = WsInsecureOptions();

              await this.managedMqttClientSubscriber.StartAsync(
                      new ManagedMqttClientOptions
                      {
                          ClientOptions = insecureOptions
                      });
          }



          List<MqttTopicFilter> topicFilter = new List<MqttTopicFilter>();
          topicFilter.Add(new MqttTopicFilter { Topic = topicThisHost });
          topicFilter.Add(new MqttTopicFilter { Topic = topicSubFromHar });

          Console.WriteLine("We have subscribed to multiple !");

          await this.managedMqttClientSubscriber.SubscribeAsync(topicFilter);
     }

      public async Task StartPublisher()
      {
          var mqttFactory = new MqttFactory();
          this.managedMqttClientPublisher = mqttFactory.CreateManagedMqttClient();

          // If tls is enabled in app.config, we use wss with cert file
          if (MqttUseTls)
          {
              var managedClientOptions = WsSecureClientOptions();
              managedClientOptions.AutoReconnectDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
              await this.managedMqttClientPublisher.StartAsync(managedClientOptions);
          }
          else
          {
              var insecureOptions = WsInsecureOptions();
              await this.managedMqttClientPublisher.StartAsync(
                  new ManagedMqttClientOptions
                  {
                      ClientOptions = insecureOptions
                  });
          }

          applog.Debug($"In StartPublisher()");

          await Publish($"{defaultMessage}  -  Machine: {this.machineName}, Host: {this.SynergyHostName}", this.topicThisHost);            
      }
        
       public async Task Publish(string messageIn, string topic, IManagedMqttClient pubClient = null)
      {
          MqttQualityOfServiceLevel qos = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce;
          switch (MqttQos)
          {
              case 0:
                  qos = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce;
                  break;
              case 1:
                  qos = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtMostOnce;
                  break;
              case 2:
                  qos = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.ExactlyOnce;
                  break;
          }
          MqttModel message = new MqttModel();
          message.message = messageIn;
          message.datestamp = DateTime.Now;
          message.source = "";
          message.status = "";
          var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, Formatting.Indented);

          var send = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
              .WithTopic(topic)
              .WithPayload(payload)
              .WithQualityOfServiceLevel(qos)
              .WithRetainFlag(false)
              .Build();

          if (this.managedMqttClientPublisher == null)
          {
              this.managedMqttClientPublisher = pubClient;
          }

          if (this.managedMqttClientPublisher != null)
          {
              try
              {
                  applog.Debug($"Mqtt Service Publish() method - about to pub mqtt message EnqueueAsync() - {messageIn} / {topic} ");
                  await this.managedMqttClientPublisher.EnqueueAsync(send);
                  MonitoringLogs logs = new MonitoringLogs();
                  logs.InsertIntoLog(message);
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  string errorMessage = $"Exception occured in Publish() method. {ex.Message}";
                  applog.Error(errorMessage);
                  throw new Exception(errorMessage);
              }
          }
          else
          {
              applog.Info($"Mqtt Service Publish() method - managedMqttClientPublisher object appears to be NULL");
          }
      }
  
  public ManagedMqttClientOptions WsSecureClientOptions()
        {
            string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MqttService)).CodeBase);

            // Building out the secure wss url (both pfx/crt certificate file types appear to work here)
            var url = $"{mqttBrokerAddress}:{mqttPort}/mqtt";

            X509Certificate2 x509Cert = null;
            var file = CertificateFileName;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, file).Remove(0, 6);

            // pfx file contains both pub and priv keys (needs pswd); crt file only has pub key (no pswd req'd)
            if (Path.GetExtension(CertificateFileName.ToLower()) == ".pfx")
            {
                // using a PFX cert file via the X509 class
                x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(filePath, CertificatePwd);
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(CertificateFileName.ToLower()) == ".crt")
            {
                x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(filePath);
            }

            applog.Debug($"In WsSecureClientOptions(), Certificate Path - {filePath}");          

            var clientOptionsBldr = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                        .WithProtocolVersion(MqttProtocolVersion.V500)
                                        .WithWebSocketServer(url)
                                        .WithCredentials(mqttClientUser, mqttClientPswd)
                                        .WithClientId(clientId)
                                        .WithCleanSession()
                                        .WithCredentials(mqttClientUser, mqttClientPswd)
                                        .WithTls(
                                            new MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters()
                                            {
                                                UseTls = true,
                                                SslProtocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
                                                Certificates = new List<X509Certificate2>() { x509Cert }                                              
                                            });
            ManagedMqttClientOptions managedClientOptions = null;
            try
            {
                applog.Debug($"In WsSecureClientOptions(), about to Build Publisher - ${url}");
                managedClientOptions = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                                                .WithClientOptions(clientOptionsBldr)
                                                                .Build();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                applog.Error("CERT ERROR ! Exception in WsSecureClientOptions() " + ex.Message);
            }

            return managedClientOptions;
        }

    private Task OnSubscriberConnected(MqttClientConnectedEventArgs _)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task OnSubscriberDisconnected(MqttClientDisconnectedEventArgs _)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
 }
```

Comment: As per the [MQTT spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/mqtt-v5.0.html#_CONNECT_Actions) "If the ClientID represents a Client already connected to the Server, the Server sends a DISCONNECT packet to the existing Client with Reason Code of 0x8E (Session taken over) as described in section 4.13 and MUST close the Network Connection of the existing Client" (due to this "piling up lots of new ClientID connections" does not make sense). A second connection is being established somehow. Add logging to your code and see if it is creating multiple connections (or use a local broker).

Comment: @Brits - Okay right, I see those specs thank you. I also see how it will check the `Clean Start` flag (section 3.1.2.4). The strange thing is that, in my in my previous version of my code, I was concatenating random num to my clientID each time my Win Svc started up. Therefore I don't understand why it was finding the same clientID each time.

Comment: That is why a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is so important. If you were getting that error with a random Client ID then the issue is probably either an error in your code (inadvertently starting a second connection with that ID) or in the library (less likely). Without fully working code we have to guess. If using random client ID's then use `Clean Start` = `true` (1); otherwise it depends on your requirements (i.e. use of QOS1+).

Comment: @Brits - I have read the `MRE` page, and I do believe I have provided clear code that people can easily read - as well as the clear errors I'm getting. If there's something missing in my post, I'm grateful if  you would point it out; I'll make any appropriate updates. I'm not sure, however, how to provide an actual working example online (if that's what you had in mind). Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: you have provided a class that relies on unseen configuration (e.g. `AppSettings`) and calls functions that are not included (also includes functions that do not appear to be used). Ideally the code provided should be the absolute minimum required to duplicate the issue and we should be able to run this ourselves (using a public broker like `broker.hivemq.com` is great). Often I find that producing such a minimal example reveals the issue (because when you minimise the code it works and then you start adding stuff back in). Currently I cannot see where your code connects.

Comment: @Brits - I'm working on hard-coding my configuration settings into my `Init()` method; this way it will be clearer to the reader what my values are. I also added `StartSubscriber()` and `StartPublisher()` methods. My apologies for missing that.

Comment: OK - this is a bit of a guess due to incomplete info but both `StartSubscriber` and `StartPublisher` are calling `CreateManagedMqttClient()` and then `StartAsync`. This will result in two connections being created. As both connections will use the same ID you will end up with the connect/disconnect loop mentioned previously. Either create a single client (best option!) or use different Client ID's.

Comment: @Brits - plz put your last comment as the answer. Both StartSub and StartPub were using the same Client ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments your code was creating two connections to the broker; once each in:

- `StartSubscriber()`
- `StartPublisher()`

Both functions end up creating a connection to the broker with the same client id (as they both use the same `WsSecureClientOptions()`/`WsInsecureOptions()`).

[MQTT-3.1.4-2](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718032) states:

> If the ClientId represents a Client already connected to the Server then the Server MUST disconnect the existing Client.

So the two connections will end up "fighting" - one will connect, leading to the other disconnecting, it will try to reconnect etc.

To solve this either:

- Use one connection (there is no need to use separate connections for subscribing/publishing)
- Use different client ID's.